# Spring security dynamic authorization and authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I founded this xml spring security configuration on the web in order to create a dynamic role authentication:

```
<bean id="filter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
<property name="accessDecisionManager">
     <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="decisionVoters" >
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
            <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
        </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>
</property>
<property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="dbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I am trying to replace it with annotation and for this purpose i created this bean:

```
@Bean
public FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor(AuthenticationManager auth) {

    List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
    RoleVoter decisionVoter = new RoleVoter();
    decisionVoter.setRolePrefix("");
    decisionVoters.add(decisionVoter);
    FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor = new FilterSecurityInterceptor();
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setAuthenticationManager(auth);
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(
            new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters));
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setSecurityMetadataSource(dbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource);
    return filterSecurityInterceptor;
}
```

This is my DbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource class:

```
@Component
public class DbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource, InitializingBean{
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.class.getName());

@Autowired
private UUsersService userService;

@Autowired
UrlCache urlCache;

private HashMap<String, List<String>> urlRoles;

@Override
public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    FilterInvocation fi=(FilterInvocation)object;
    String url=fi.getRequestUrl();
    logger.debug("Request Url====>"+url);

    List<String> roles_=urlRoles.get(url);
    logger.debug("Ruoli associati all'url :"+roles_);
    if(roles_==null){
        return null;
    }
    logger.debug("------------------");
    String[] stockArr = new String[roles_.size()];
    stockArr = roles_.toArray(stockArr);
    return SecurityConfig.createList(stockArr);
}

@Override
public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    userService.getUrlRoles();
    this.urlRoles=urlCache.getUrlRoles();
    logger.debug("Oggetto ruoli/urls :"+urlRoles);
}

}
```

Now, all urls are intercepted from filter and roles associated to them but i'm not able to understand how to link roles of logged user with ones retrieved from url requested.
In my loadByUsername method implementation, i recover roles associated to loggedUser in this way:

```
    public PMAuthenticationUserDetails loadPMUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    PMAuthenticationUserDetails userDTO = null;
    try{
        // get anagrafica
        UUsers user = usersDao.findUserByUsername(username);

        if(user != null){
            // get role
            List<UAuthorities> authorities = userAuthorityDao.findAuthoritiesByUserId(user.getId());

            //get urls
            List<UResource> urls = authorityResourceDao.findUrlsByAuthorities(authorities);

            logger.info("L'utente con username: " + username + " esiste e ha n° " + authorities.size() + " ruoli associati.");

            /** per spring */
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authoritiesDTO = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

            /** lista codici ruoli (Stringhe prive del prefisso spring "ROLE_" */
            List<String> codeAuthorities = new ArrayList<String>();

            logger.info("Elenco ruoli: ");

            for (UAuthorities item : authorities) {
                logger.info(AuthenticationType.PREFIX_ROLE + item.getAuthority());
                /**
                 * Quindi creiamo un oggetto di SimpleGrantedAuthority per passare quel ruolo in esso.
                 */
                authoritiesDTO.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthenticationType.PREFIX_ROLE + item.getAuthority()));
                /**
                 * Aggiungo alla lista il codice del ruolo.
                 */
                codeAuthorities.add(item.getAuthority());
            }

            /**
             * Dopo valorizziamo l' oggetto user personalizzato che avrà il nome utente, le credenziali, ed 
             * eventuali altri campi come e-mail ecc.
             */
            userDTO = new PMAuthenticationUserDetails(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authoritiesDTO);
            // set custom property
            userDTO.setUserId(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
            userDTO.setFirstname(user.getFirstname());
            userDTO.setLastname(user.getLastname());
            userDTO.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            userDTO.setAvatar(user.getAvatar());
            userDTO.setRoles(codeAuthorities);
        }else
            logger.error("L'utente con username: " + username + " >>> NON E' STATO TROVATO IN TABELLA.");

        return userDTO;
    }catch(Exception e ){
        logger.error("loadPMUserByUsername >>> " + e, e);
        return userDTO;
    }
}
```

I need something more in my configuration?

`

Comment: Did you find any solution for your question ?

Comment: https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-security-dynamic-authorization-and-authentication